# Exclude a directory from `podman/docker export` stream and save to a file

Tags: containers, tar, podman

I have a container that I want to export as a `.tar` file. I have used a `podman run` with a `tar --exclude=/dir1 --exclude=/dir2 …` that outputs to a file located on a bind-mounted host dir. But recently this [has been giving me some `tar: .: file changed as we read it`](https://github.com/containers/fuse-overlayfs/issues/384) errors, which `podman/docker export` would avoid. Besides, the `export` I suppose is  more efficient. So I'm trying to migrate to using the `export`, but the major obstacle is I can't seem to find a way to exclude paths from the tar stream.

If possible, I'd like to avoid modifying a tar archive already saved on disk, and instead modify the stream before it gets saved to a file.

I've been banging my head for multiple hours, trying useless advices from ChatGPT, looking at `cpio`, and attempting to pipe the `podman export` to `tar --exclude …` command. With the last I did have small success at some point, but couldn't make tar save the result to a particularly named file.

Any suggestions?

*(note: I do not make distinction between docker and podman here as their export command is completely the same, and it's useful for searchability)*

Comment: @BMitch why you removed `docker` tag? The question equally applies to docker, which I explicitly mention at the bottom of the post

Comment: Nothing directed specifically at you. When I see questions tagged with both docker and podman, but only talking about podman, I remove the docker tag to avoid confusion between the two. In this case, I'd argue that it's not even a podman question since neither tool offers the feature you want, and instead you solved it with a shell pipe and a tar utility that would apply to any command outputting a tar file.

Comment: @BMitch well, infrastructure questions in general, such as about toolchains, utilties, etc, i.e. anything not directly related to programming languages, often have answers in terms of other projects. E.g. if you have a question about GCC linking, an answer might involve an alternative linker, such as `mold` for example. Or a question about `sh` intricacies might involve using sh-compatible `bash`. The question here isn't in any way different: neither Docker nor Podman apparently provide a way of dealing with the problem… They might in the future, but for now an answer involves another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224857/59928#how-can-i-filter-the-contents-of-a-tar-file-producing-another-tar-file-in-the-p), I found that `bsdtar` *(as opposed to the usual `tar`)* does have the ability to filter out files from `stdin`. It's implemented by passing `-f -` for "write to stdout" and `@-` for "read from stdin".

So, suppose I want to filter out all dirs containing `etc` and `lib64`, then I execute:

```bash
λ podman export frosty_banach | bsdtar -czf - --exclude="etc" --exclude="lib64" @- > foo.tar.gz
λ tar tf foo.tar.gz | grep -P "\betc|lib64"
    # no matches, the dirs were filtered out successfully
```

The usual glob expansion with `*` is also supported as part of pattern-matching.

Comment: Marking "accepted" for now, but better answers are welcome. This filtering is just a workaround, because it still requires `docker` and `podman` to read megabytes of data from disk just for them to get filtered out. Ideally they should be just skipped instead.